# How to create different underline colour for my heading text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a single underline below my heading text `<h1>` tag. But the colour of the underline below text should have a different colour than rest.

Below is the image for my requirement. 
[image: Heading Text with different underline colour]

What I have tried doing is placing two `<div>` side by side and setting different border bottom colour. But this is not a best practice to follow.

Please suggest some improvements to my code.

```css
#left {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  float: left
}

#right {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <h1>My Heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <h1>Transparent Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give the parent a bottom border, set the heading to `inline-block` so it's width is contained to the text size, give the heading a bottom border, then shift the heading down 3px so the borders overlap.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give `H1` red border and black border to the `span` inside it. Use padding to fix the alignment of borders.

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding:3px 0;
}

h1 span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  padding:4px 0
}
```

```html
  <h1><span>heading</span></h1>
```

Comment: its look good on my chrome and mozilla, I am on chrome Version 57.0.2987.110

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding:3px 0;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:3px;
background:#333;
content:"";
bottom:-3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>heading</h1>
```